# Observed Object not Registered as an Observer

Tags: objective-c, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nsmanagedobject, nsarraycontroller

I am having an issue when my array controller is refreshed with new data retrieved from a server request.

**The Setup**

I have an entity object (call it `MyParent`) which has a few properties:

```
name
age
description
widgetID
```

And an entity object (call it MyWidget) which has a few properties:

```
name
size
description
```

The size is a string representation of an `NSSize` object. It makes for easy storage and retrieval from the core data store and to the server and back in JSON. In order to represent the size in the UI, I have subclassed the MyWidget and provided a custom setter and getter as a category of the custom class (I did this so Xcode doesn't overwrite my changes if I need to make changes to the model):

```
-(void)setObjectWidth:(NSInteger)aValue {
    [self setObjectSize:NSMakeSize(aValue, [self objectHeight])];
}

-(void)setObjectHeight:(NSInteger)aValue {
    [self setObjectSize:NSMakeSize([self objectWidth], aValue)];
}

-(void)setObjectSize:(NSSize)aValue {
    [self setSize:NSStringFromSize(aValue)];
}

-(NSInteger)objectWidth {
    return [self objectSize].width;
}

-(NSInteger)objectHeight {
    return [self objectSize].height;
}

-(NSSize)objectSize {
    return NSSizeFromString([self size]);
}
```

I get the `widget` by doing a lookup on the `widgetId` as a category method on the parent:

```
-(MyWidget *)widget {
    NSManagedObjectContext * moc = [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];

    return [moc fetchObjectForEntityName:@"MyWidget"
                                 withUID:[self widgetID]];
}
```

The fetchObjectForEntityName:withUID is a category on the managed object context.

Within the UI I have an array controller bound to a tableView of `MyParent` objects. Selecting an object presents the details in the UI which are bound to the appropriate values:

```
parentArrayController --> parentArray (managed objects in an array)
parentTable --> parentArrayController.arrangedObjects.name

uiWidthTextField --> parentArrayController.selection.widget.objectWidth
uiHeightTextField --> parentArrayController.selection.widget.objectHeight
```

The array controller is observed for changes so that it can fire off a notification for other parts of the app that need to know the selected object changed

**What Works**

Everything works well. I can make changes to the text fields within the UI and it sets and gets the size from the widget as you would expect. Adding a parent item is a simple task of creating a NSURLConnection and sending the appropriate params off to the server. When the server acknowledges the add, I request the list of parent items form the server again.

The list that comes down is compared to the existing list in core data and adds the new item and makes any other changes to other object values that are already there.

**What's Broken**

When the list comes back, it is parsed correctly, but the app complains when the array controller is being updated:

> Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing: Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "widget.objectHeight" from  because it is not registered as an observer. with userInfo (null)
>
> Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "widget.objectHeight" from  because it is not registered as an observer.

**What I've Tried**

I have tried to add a willChangeValueForKey: and didChangeValueForKey: wrapped around the setter of the objectHeight and objectWidth, but this seems to provide no recourse.

I believe the issue is because IB is bound to the `widget.objectHeight` and widget is a lookup on the parent as opposed to a true KVO/KVC property. However, I don't need a setter on `widget` (although I'll be trying that next).

I know I'm missing something, but can't place my finger on it.

**The Plea**

Any help or assistance with resolving this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `objectWidth` and `objectHeight` as non-modeled properties of MyWidget. You are having KVO problems because `objectWidth` and `objectHeight`are not keys of MyWidget but just have method names in the form of getters and setters.

Just add:

```
@property() NSInteger objectWidth;
@property() NSInteger objectHeight;
```

to the MyWidget class and that should provide the keys for KVO to work. (Might want to double check my property form. It's been a while sense I had to write an integer property.)

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried adding the @property to the model, but it didn't make a difference. I then wrapped each setter/getter with the appropriate willChangeValue and also willAccessValue. No joy. I then moved these off the category and onto the model object directly. Still no luck :-( As best I can tell it is failing as you pointed out. And that makes sense. I also tried disabling the automatic notification with automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey and returning NO for those keys (objectHeight etc). Frustrating to say the least!

Comment: finally got back around to closing out my open issues. Your solution worked. I had not realized that I had set the setters and getters to not do automatic notification and therefore the synthesized setter and getters were not firing KVC notifications. Quick fix and everything worked just fine. Thanks!